# Can I push notification using FCM without upload p12 or p8 certificate file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apn

I have problem with my company's project. Other team building server and my job is only frontend.But I can't receive any notification. They said they use FCM to push notification but on project setting -> Cloud Message on firebase console not have any p8 or p12 certificate file is uploaded. I have no idea about that, i'm new on firebase tech, anyone have idea for that.

Comment: Read the documentation, it sounds like you haven't even tried

Comment: it's not possible without certificate. it something like "unlock lock without key"

Comment: @SPatel i understand that, but there are other guy doing code phase 1 of my app, and it receive notification, and they said they using FCM . I don't understand why

Comment: ask them, we do not know how your team has done something. to send/receive push notifications on iOS you MUST have a certificate

Comment: they're gone, and bring their code away, it's the problem. :))

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/   you should read this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see anything under the APNs Authentication Key section?

There is a way to send push with APNs Authentication Key. Check out this link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key. Probably this will help.